# Linux - How to make grep show the next line too

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, logging

I am using grep to see a log of one of our systems.

When I type "cat server.log | grep PPHI245" it shows the output below:

[image]

But, when I type just "cat server.log" it shows the output below:

[image]

Look the red underlined text that I marked on the screenshot. It is the continuation of the error message.

Please, I would like to use grep to display the full error message, not just the first line of the error.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi have you tried using `-A 1` argument? So it will return one extraline after match. Or you can use `-n` option in a script in such a way that if the next matching line difference is anything but 2 then print the line?

Comment: Thanks @dmb. I used this command and served me very well.